# NoSuchMethodError for addall ArrayList in JNI

Tags: java, arraylist, java-native-interface

```
jclass class= env->FindClass("java/util/ArrayList"); 

listClass = (jclass)env->NewGlobalRef(class);   

listAddAllID = env->GetMethodID(listClass, "addAll", "(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z");
```

I got the following exception for the above code "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: addAll".I used 'lang/object' for a parameter and 'z' for return type boolean.It seems to be right completely.What am I missing here?

> public boolean addAll(Collection c)

Comment: A `Collection` is very different from an `Object[]' . Wild guess: `env->GetMethodID(listClass, "addAll", "(java/util/Collection;)Z")`

Comment: It works by changing the object into collection. Thanks Gyro.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use `javap` to get proper descriptor of method

```
> javap -s java.util.ArrayList | grep -A +1 addAll
  public boolean addAll(java.util.Collection<? extends E>);
    descriptor: (Ljava/util/Collection;)Z
--
  public boolean addAll(int, java.util.Collection<? extends E>);
    descriptor: (ILjava/util/Collection;)Z
```

So, you need to change it to one of these (depending on the call you want to make).

Have fun with JNI!

Comment: I tried the command mentioned and got a clear idea.Thank you for an example.

Comment: .oOo. Great! Have fun with JNI! .oOo.

Answer (score 0):

> It seems to be right completely.

Incomprehensible. It is completely wrong. The API says the parameter is a `Collection`.

Don't guess at these things, and don't try to write JNI method sigmatures yourself. Use the output of `javap -s`. It is never wrong.

Comment: Don't know this until you say.Really good way to write a JNI method.Thank you.